# Does com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture .get() inside a coroutine blocks the thread even in `runInterruptible`

Tags: kotlin, grpc, grpc-java, grpc-kotlin

Using gRPC response of `com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture` and calling `get` on it, is it blocking the thread that does the `get()` call?

Or because I'm inside a coroutine the thread is free and only resumed when the network response arrived?

Notice that I'm starting from a rest controller with suspend method.

Kotlin code calling to Java gRPC library:

```
@RestController
class SomeController(

  @GetMapping("/create-table")
  suspend fun createTable(@RequestBody request: CreateCDPTableRequest): CreateTableResponse {

val response: ListenableFuture<Response> = stub.some-grpc-call(requestBuilder.build())

return runInterruptible(Dispatchers.IO) {
       response.get()
      }
}
}
```

Is there a way to use it as non-blocking?

Comment: `ListenableFuture.get()` is not a `suspend` function, it's a blocking call. So, the thread is blocked.

Comment: I edited the question, and added the scope of a suspend rest endpoint.
Also, asked what is the way to do it non-blocking?

Comment: See the [`await()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-guava/kotlinx.coroutines.guava/await.html) extension function.

Comment: I don't have option for `await()` on the `ListenableFuture`, only `addListener`

Comment: If you mean you don't have the necessary dependency, just add it. If you mean you're not allowed to add that dependency, then unfortunately I can't help you. Perhaps you can look at the [implementation](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/integration/kotlinx-coroutines-guava/src/ListenableFuture.kt#L230) and try to create your own version of `await()`.

Comment: I see the issue, the gRPC protos were compiled to JAVA, so it is `com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture` and not `kotlinx.coroutines.guava.ListenableFuture`, I cannot manage to compile into kotlin

Comment: Not sure I understand. The `await()` function is an [_extension_ function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html#extension-functions) defined for `com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture`. Extension functions can be defined for non-Kotlin types. Note this extension function is defined in a separate coroutine module than the core module: [kotlinx-coroutines-guava](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/integration/kotlinx-coroutines-guava/README.md). You can see all the modules [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines#modules).

Comment: thanks, I was missing it, will try it.